# Wrapping all the images with <figure> in the webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok. So I am trying to add this [CSSgram](http://una.im/CSSgram/) to all the images in my webpage.

This is used for adding instagram like filters to the images. Images should be wrapped with a `<figure class-"aden"> </figure>` in order to add the effect.

So i tried it, but most of the images seem to break or stretch and are not in order. Before-[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v356t2yz/2/) and After [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/v356t2yz/1/)

So is there any other way to apply this effect without the need to wrap in `<figure>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove the `height="400"` on the first image ?

Besides, `<figure>` tag is a block-element instead of `<img>` who is inline. So you will have to put `display: inline-block;` property on figure element to get the right set.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to apply the width and height of the images on the `img` tag. Do it in CSS instead:

```js
$(function() {
 $("img").wrap("<figure class='_1977'></figure>");
});
```

```css
figure {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cssgram-cssgram.netdna-ssl.com/cssgram.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/IMiabf0.jpg">

<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/fG0o394ga/135.gif" >
```

Answer (score -1):

Just apply the needed class to your img tags:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/IMiabf0.jpg" class="_1977">
```

Here's the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/v356t2yz/27/